# A different path to cofinite topology not being T2

Tags: general-topology

I've seen that the cofinite topology on a general infinite space, $(X, \tau_{cf} = \{V\subset X: X\setminus V \text{ is finite or }X \}),$ is not T2 since there are no disjoint open sets at all. However, I'm currently working on a problem that seeks the same goal through the following setup:
Given $(X,\tau_{fc})$ where $X$ is infinite, there exists a sequence of nested non-empty compact sets $K_1\supset K_2\supset K_3\supset\dots$ such that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty K_n = \emptyset.$ This implies that $(X, \tau_{cf})$ is not Hausdorff.

The first part is easy enough. We take $K = \{x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots\} \subset X$ to be countable and form $K_n = K\setminus\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}.$ Each $K_n$ is compact since the whole space is and for any $n\in\mathbb{N}, x_n \not\in K_n,$ so the intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty K_n = \emptyset.$
But then we have to relate this back to open sets and a really general statement at that. There exists some $x,y\in X$ such that any pair of neighborhoods $x\in V_x, y\in U_y$ intersect, $V_x \cap U_y \ne \emptyset.$ I'm just lost at a starting point to relate one particular sequence to an arbitrary choice of open sets.

Comment: This relies on some known properties: 1. Every compact subset of a $T_2$ space is closed, and 2. Nested closed, compact sets have non-empty, closed, compact intersection (Cantor's Intersection Theorem). If $X$ were $T_2$, then any nested family of compact sets are automatically closed, and hence their intersection is non-empty. But, clearly, this is not the case.

Comment: @TheoBendit: You should post this as an answer

Comment: @tomasz I only post comments on topology questions, just in case Henno doesn't get around to writing an answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is an indirect proof: If $X$ is Hausdorff every compact subset of $X$ is closed.

This fact by itself is already enough to refute the Hausdorffness of $(X,\tau_{cf})$: if $X$ is infinite write it as two the union of two disjoint infinite sets $A$ and $B$. Then $A$ and $B$ are compact (the subspace topology is just the cofinite topology on that subset, hence compact) but neither is closed because it doesn't have finite complement.

But your text wishes a different route: A standard theorem is that a nested intersection of *closed* compact subsets has non-empty intersection. A corollary (combining with the compact implies closed fact):

> If $X$ is Hausdorff, a nested intersection of compact subsets has non-empty intersection.

Your sets $K_n$ are compact in $K$ (and if $X$ were Hausdorff, they would also be closed...) and nested and yet have empty-intersection. So the Hausdorffness is again indirectly refuted: a fact that would hold in a Hausdorff space does not hold.

There is no way to go back to disjoint open sets. We just refute it **indirectly** by showing that a theorem that does hold in all Hausdorff spaces does not hold in this space.

I find it somewhat convoluted myself. It does illustrate that we cannot omit the closed in closed and compact in the nested intersection theorem.
I'd rather see it in that light.